# Bruhat-Tits theory and Jordan-Chevalley decomposition

Tags: lie-groups, buildings

The theory of Bruhat-Tits buildings is known to be able to unify some Lie group decompositions. Is there a sense in which an appropriate choice of building can unify the Jordan-Chevalley with the Cartan with the Iwasawa with the Bruhat decomposition? Learning the theory would seem rather challenging in order only to obtain an answer to this question.

Comment: Maybe since topologically unipotent elements are defined in terms of parahoric subgroups you expect topological Jordan decomposition to be visible from the geometry of the building?

Comment: @KentaSuzuki, from [that](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/445499/bruhat-tits-theory-and-jordan-chevalley-decomposition#comment1150669_445499) point of view one might expect the Jordan decomposition to be visible from the geometry of the spherical building.  That sounds like the sort of thing that could be true, but I don't know how to do it.  Do you?